# Why is Session always empty in PHP7 wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, php-7

We have a wordpress site which uses PHP7. Session is always empty after we upgraded to PHP7. It was working fine in PHP5 versions.

Comment: Hi @Rads, did you find any solution for this? Because I am facing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hook a function on "init" in your functions.php like this :

```
function ur_theme_start_session()
{

if (!session_id())
    session_start();
}

add_action("init", "ur_theme_start_session", 1);
```